# 40k - Which chars, (excl Primarchs) were directly influenced by the Gods of Chaos (see: Ahriman)

Tags: warhammer-40k, space-marines

I have read a whole lot of 40k books in my time but only very recently came along the Ahriman Trilogie (which is outright fantastic).
In the third book, there are 2-3 pages that ACTUALLY shift the scenery to the actual Court of Change , its inner workings and how the Changer of Ways, Tzeentch, directly influences Ahrimans fate **at least** from then on.

To the best of my knowledge, over 50+ novels over the years i never did read anything as specific in terms of the Gods of Chaos.

This has got me thinking:

Can anyone name more characters that were **directly** influenced by the Gods of Chaos, and can you name which book, scene, codex etc act as evidence ?

Comment: Every named daemon and every named Eldar. Every Primarch (when they were scattered). You might need to narrow your definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly Erebus and Kor Phaeron

> Erebus is one of the most prominent members of the Word Bearers Chaos Space Marines and a member of the Dark Council of Sicarus. He was the harbinger of the Horus Heresy, instrumental in converting first Lorgar and then Horus to Chaos. Erebus refers to himself as the Hand of Destiny, the mortal instrument of the plans of the Ruinous Powers.
>
> From the Lexicanum [article on Erebus](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Erebus)

> As Lorgar took command of his Legion, Kor Phaeron became his second-in-command, becoming the First Captain of the Word Bearers Legion. Along with Erebus, Kor Phaeron was among the first of the Adeptus Astartes to fall to Chaos and create the first Chaos Space Marines by converting his Primarch and Legion. He is currently the Keeper of the Faith of the Legion.
>
> From the Lexicanum [article on Kor Phaeron](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Kor_Phaeron)

So, these two have already fallen to Chaos before any other Astartes and were downright responsible for Lorgar Aurelian discovering and therefore falling to Chaos. Furthermore, Erebus was responsible for Horus Lupercal falling to Chaos:

> Falling unconscious, under the advice of Word Bearers First Chaplain Erebus, the natives of the world helped to heal him. However, unknown to the desperate Mournival, the healers and Erebus himself, had all since become corrupted by Chaos and were orchestrating the entire series of events. Having his dying body moved to the Serpent Lodge, Horus was soon subjected to an ancient Chaos ritual by the Davin priests, while Erebus entered his mind disguised as the deceased Hastur Sejanus. This image of Sejanus showed Horus horrifying visions of the future, where the Emperor ruled as a god and had discarded the Primarchs once they had outlived their usefulness. Erebus also told Horus that the Gods of Chaos were peaceful beings with little interest in the Materium, and it was the Emperor that was intent on destroying their realm on his quest for godhood.
>
> From the Lexicanum [article on Horus Lupercal](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Horus_Lupercal#The_Betrayal)

Furthermore, there was Typhus of the Death Guard Legion:

> According to Typhon himself, he was secretly converted to worship of the Gods of Chaos during the Zaramund Campaign, receiving revelation at the touch of the hand of an old woman. Typhon's allegiance to Chaos predated that of his own Primarch, or of Horus himself. With the help of his new gods, Typhon became First Captain of the Death Guard and commander of the battleship Terminus Est. Typhon was not particularly loyal to Mortarion, and always wished to travel the Galaxy and forge his own destiny in the name of the Ruinous Powers.
>
> From the Lexicanum [article on Typhus](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Typhus)

Following this trend of a Chosen for each Chaos God, there is also Khârn The Betrayer:

> As Khorne's greatest champion, Khârn enjoys the Blessing of the Blood God, which renders him immune to the effects of psychic powers. In addition, since he has become Daemonically corrupted Kharn exudes a blood mist wherever he walks. This mist allows for the manifestation of Daemonic creatures and can drive lesser foes to madness.
>
> From the Lexicanum [article on Khârn](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Kh%C3%A2rn)

Furthermore, Lucius the Eternal

> Lucius continued to hone and better his combat skills after the Emperor's Children began to worship Slaanesh. Fulgrim organized gladiatorial games on their home planet whenever the Legion was unable to vent its need for the pleasure of the kill on other worlds, and Lucius was undefeated in these, an unstoppable force, until he fought Lord Commander Cyrius. Lucius died, and his death was an experience of such transcendent pleasure that Slaanesh himself took notice: he could not let such a promising marine slip away. In the following days, Cyrius began to change: lines began to appear over his skin and his hair started to fall out. Lucius was back in the world of the living, and all that remained of Cyrius was a screaming face in the warped artificer armour. This has happened many times since then: whenever his killer takes even the tiniest moment of enthusiasm, pleasure, or satisfaction from besting Lucius, they will begin to change into him and become just another swirling face, a memory in the armor in which Lucius is clad.[1](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Erebus) Not even the mechanical Necrons are immune from this curse, as the Phasing Sword has learned. After every "death" Lucius reborned again, as arrogant and maniacal as ever and immediately looking for a new challenge to fight.
>
> From the Lexicanum [article on Lucius the Eternal](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Lucius_the_Eternal)

And as you mentioned, Ahriman for Tzeentch.

There are a lot of other Space Marines being chosen for some blessings. Abaddon the Despoiler can be considereed  as the chosen of all Chaos Gods but he doesn't let them influence him, as he saw that as Horus'es weakness:

> Ezekyle Abaddon, more commonly known as Abaddon the Despoiler, is the Warmaster of Chaos, the former First Captain of the Sons of Horus Legion and now absolute Master of the Black Legion, and rumoured to be the clone-progeny of Warmaster Horus. He is the most powerful Warmaster of all, successor to Horus, and blessed by all four of the Gods of Chaos. Despite being the Warmaster of Chaos, Abaddon has refused giving himself fully over to the Ruinous Powers as the Daemon Primarchs have, as this would limit his existence beyond the Eye of Terror and push his ultimate vengeance against the Imperium beyond his grasp.
>
> From the Lexicanum [article on Ezekyle Abaddon](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Ezekyle_Abaddon)

Comment: @user431806 As for the source of those, read the Lexicanum articles I've linked. In there, the source is cited.

Comment: Splendid answer !

Comment: There is a whitescars commander who was also corrupted by Chaos, he attempted to lead Khan to the dark side. 

I would argue there is a difference though between those who where directly influenced by the chaos gods, and those who where tricked/manipulated.